# Error to moves from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android

Error shows can not cast Highlight to Fragment and can not cast Overview to Fragment and error comes only in selectFrag() method. Please any one help me to fix this problem. I want to switch one fragment to other when i click on textview item.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }        

     public void selectFrag(View view){      
        Fragment fr;
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.txt_highlite)) {          
        fr = (Fragment) new Highlight();
        }
        else{
            fr = (Fragment) new Overview();
        }       
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.place_holder, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
    }
```

//Highlight class

```
public class Highlight extends Fragment {   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.highlight, container, false);
    }
}
```

//Overview class

```
public class Overview extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview, container, false);
    }
}
```

//activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
      <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_projectoverview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_Projectoverview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Project Overview"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/project_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"          
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_overview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Overview" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_highlite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Highlight" />            
        </LinearLayout>          
    </RelativeLayout>   

     <fragment 
          android:name="com.example.fragment_move.Overview"
          android:id="@+id/place_holder"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare fr as Fragment, but you create a Highlight.

Highlight extends Fragment, but you need to cast it to Fragment to use it in an FragmentTransaction.

So try this:

```
public void selectFrag(View view){      
        Fragment fr;
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.txt_highlite)) {          
        fr = (Fragment) new Highlight();
        }
        else{
            fr = (Fragment) new Overview();
        }       
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.place_holder, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```